# How to catch unhandled exceptions globally in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to handle every single exeption in one global handler in my app.
I created an objective-c header file and implementation file and then created bridging file to access the objective-c code in swift code. After that in AppDelegate I set the UncaughtExceptionHandler but the handler does not call. What I am doing wrong?

UncaughtExceptionHandler.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

volatile void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception);
extern NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *exceptionHandlerPtr;


@interface UncaughtExceptionHandler : NSObject

@end
```

UncaughtExceptionHandler.m

```
#import "UncaughtExceptionHandler.h"


@implementation UncaughtExceptionHandler

volatile void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    printf("TEST");
}

NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *exceptionHandlerPtr = &exceptionHandler;

@end
```

Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "UncaughtExceptionHandler.h"
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerPtr)

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you believe it isn't being called? How are you raising your exception? You may misunderstand what exceptions are in ObjC. Accessing an array out of bounds, for instance, is not an ObjC exception.

If you mean "things that would crash the app," then that is a very complicated thing to write, and you should not try to write it yourself. You want to use something like [PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org). Even if you were going to write it yourself, you should first study PLCrashReporter in depth to understand everything they do. Did I mention that it's complicated? Very small mistakes (say, trying to allocate memory) can deadlock the program, causing the CPU to heat up in a tight spinlock (yeah; had that bug).

It's impossible to raise an ObjC exception directly in Swift code, so there's no way that a Swift error could lead to this function being called. It would have to call something in ObjC.

It's also important to set the right expectation for "handle." By "handle" you need to mean "write the minimum state necessary for later reporting, then exit the program." If by "handle" you mean "get us back in a state where we don't crash," that's not possible. Once an exception is thrown in ObjC (whether an ObjC exception, or a hardware exception), you need to crash very soon. There is no recovery from these situations. (This is completely different from C++ or Java where exceptions are a normal part of error handling. In ObjC they are not.) That's why `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` is documented as:

> Sets the top-level error-handling function where you can perform last-minute logging **before the program terminates**.

Comment: *" If by "handle" you mean "get us back in a state where we don't crash," that's not possible. "* So true. Worth more upvotes than I can give. Note that, in particular, it's impossible to avoid leaks under ARC after "handling" a C++/ObjC exception.

Comment: @rickster There is `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` that will allow ARC to avoid leaking. If you compile for ObjC++, you'll get this by default. It adds space and time complexity, but it is possible to mix C++ exceptions with ARC (and I assume @try/@catch, too, but those are so rare).

Comment: Good to know. Still, the general advice stands — don't try to keep running after an ObjC exception. (I mentioned C++ only because ObjC exceptions use much of the same machinery.)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you are doing wrong is trying to do this in the first place. Assuming we are talking about Objective-C exceptions, they are thrown to indicate programming errors. You don't catch them. You let them crash your program, then you fix the bugs.

If you are talking about Swift try/catch/throw, that is syntactic sugar for error handling. If you call a function that can throw, you *must* catch it right there and then.